# Turn embedded python into jupyter kernel?

Tags: python, c, jupyter, embedding

I am having a code in c++ which embeds Python. I would like the Python interpreter accessible thorugh Jupyter console (qt or browser) for which I need to run kernel first. Is it possible to make the current (and only) Python interpreter act as kernel for jupyter? Otherwise said, is it possible to have the same interpreter both as Jupyter server and kernel?

After googling around, I did not find anything in that direction.